# rabbit messaging confirmation

Tags: queue, cloud, rabbitmq, bigdata

I am using rabbitmq and I want to make sure that if I have a connection problem in the client, the messages that I posted won't be lost. I simulate it with eclipse: I do system.exit the program of fetching after 100 messages. I posted 1000 messages. The second run I don't limit the number of messages and it returns me 840 messages with 3 times. Can you help me?

**the code of the producer is:**

```
public void run() {
    String json =SimpleQueueServiceSample.getFromList();
    while (!(json.equals(""))){
        json =SimpleQueueServiceSample.getFromList();
        try {   
            c.basicPublish("", "test", 
                    MessageProperties.PERSISTENT_TEXT_PLAIN, json.getBytes());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    try {
        c.waitForConfirmsOrDie();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

**the code of the consumber is:**

```
 QueueingConsumer consumer = new QueueingConsumer(channel);
 channel.basicConsume(QUEUE_NAME, true, consumer);  
  while (true) {
          System.out.println(count++);
    QueueingConsumer.Delivery delivery = consumer.nextDelivery();
    String message = new String(delivery.getBody());
    System.out.println(" [x] Received '" + message + "'");
  }
```

Comment: You use auto-ack which remove message from queue immediately after it was requested by consumer, regardless whether it was processed correct or not, was it delivered to client or not. Try to use manual message acknowledge.

Answer (score 0):

So the challenge for your scenario is how you're handling the acknowledgements.

```java
channel.basicConsume(QUEUE_NAME, true, consumer);
```

Is the problem.  The second parameter of `true` is the auto-acknowledge field.

To fix that, use:

```java
channel.basicConsume(QUEUE_NAME, false, consumer);
while (true) {
    QueueingConsumer.Delivery delivery = consumer.nextDelivery();
    //...
    channel.basicAck(delivery.getEnvelope().getDeliveryTag(), false);
}
```

---

It looks like you're using RabbitMQ's tutorials, and your code snippet is from [part one](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-java.html).  If you look at [part two](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-java.html), they start talking about acknowledgements and setting up quality of service to provide round-robin dispatch.

It's worth pointing out that the `basicConsume()` and `nextDelivery()` combination rely upon a hidden queue that lives within the consumer.  So when you call `basicConsume()` several messages are pulled down to the client to local storage.

The benefit at that approach is that it avoids additional network overhead from calling for each individual message.  The problem is that it can put more messages within your local consumer than you wish and you may lose messages if the consumer drops before processing all of the messages in the local hidden queue.

If you truly want your consumers only working on one message a time so that nothing is lost, you probably want to look at the `basicGet()` method instead of the `basicConsume()`.